# Require vba code to to webscrap the PRELIMINARY DATA section from the "https://www.cmegroup.com/markets/metals/precious/gold.volume.html"

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

[image]

[Web Link "https://www.cmegroup.com/markets/metals/precious/gold.volume.html"]

From the above website I am not able to web scrap the data table section named PRELIMINARY DATA.

I have tried a code given but no luck for this website same code is working for another website mentioned below.

["https://www.nseindia.com/market-data/live-equity-market"]

can anyone help please?

```
Sub GetTableUsingIE_From_NSE() 'Working sample code for NSE Website table
    'Refer below website for further nested code of row col
    'https://copyprogramming.com/howto/how-to-extract-data-from-website-with-vba-excel
    
    Dim ieApp As Object
    Dim url As String
    Dim htmlDoc As Object
    Dim tables As Object
    Dim table As Object
    
    ' Specify the URL of the website
    
    url = "https://www.nseindia.com/market-data/live-equity-market"
    'url = "https://www.cmegroup.com/markets/metals/precious/gold.volume.html#tradeDate=20231212"
    ' Create a new instance of Internet Explorer
    Set ieApp = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    
    ' Make IE visible (you can set it to False if you don't want to see the browser)
    ieApp.Visible = True
    
    ' Navigate to the specified URL
    ieApp.navigate url
    
    ' Wait for the page to load (you may need to adjust the wait time based on the website)
    Do While ieApp.Busy Or ieApp.readyState <> 4
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:03")
    Loop
    
    ' Get the HTML document from the loaded page
    Set htmlDoc = ieApp.document
    
'    ' Get all tables from the HTML document
'    Set tables = htmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("table")
'
'    ' Loop through each table and do something (e.g., print table contents)
'    For Each table In tables
'        ' Do something with the table, e.g., print its innerHTML
'        Debug.Print table.innerHTML
'        MsgBox table.innerHTML
'    Next table
    Dim elt As Object
    Dim aRow, aCol, totCol As Integer
    Dim sHeaderStr  As String
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").UsedRange.Clear
    With htmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("table").Item(0)
        
        aRow = 1
        aCol = 1
        For Each elt In .getElementsByTagName("th")
            Debug.Print elt.innerText
            sHeaderStr = elt.innerText
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Cells(aRow, aCol).Value = sHeaderStr
            aCol = aCol + 1
            totCol = aCol
        Next elt
        aRow = aRow + 1
        aCol = 1
        Debug.Print vbNewLine
        For Each elt In .getElementsByTagName("td") '
        
            Debug.Print elt.innerText
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Cells(aRow, aCol).Value = elt.innerText
            If aCol < 18 Then
                aCol = aCol + 1
            Else
                aCol = 1
                aRow = aRow + 1
            End If
        
        Next elt
    End With
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").UsedRange.Rows.AutoFit
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").UsedRange.Rows.WrapText = True
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").UsedRange.Rows.WrapText = False
    
    ' Close Internet Explorer
    ieApp.Quit
    Set ieApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

From the above website I am not able to web scrap the data table section named PRELIMINARY DATA.

I have tried a code given but no luck for this website same code is working for another website mentioned below.

["https://www.nseindia.com/market-data/live-equity-market"]

can anyone help please?

Comment: There isn't `PRELIMINARY DATA` on web page https://www.nseindia.com/market-data/live-equity-market . Please double check the url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the IE anymore. It's deprecated! You can get a JSON from the page with xhr (XML HTTP Request).

Here is an example how it can work:

```
Sub TotalsCMEGoldVolumeByDate()
    'This macro downloads a JSON
    'It works for the last 32 days
    'Oldest getable update for the data is yesterday - 31 days
    
    Const urlBase As String = "https://www.cmegroup.com/CmeWS/mvc/Volume/Details/F/437/"
    Const urlTail As String = "/P"
    Dim urlDate As String
    Dim quotationMarksAll() As String
    Dim quotationMarkOne As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim currRow As Long
    Dim pasteInCell As Boolean
    
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    currRow = 1
    
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
        urlDate = "20231228" 'yyyymmdd (Make this dynamic if needed)
        .Open "GET", urlBase & urlDate & urlTail, False
        .Send
        
        If .Status = 200 Then
            'Here we have a JSON like follows:
            '
            '{
            '   "tradeDate":"20231228",
            '   "totals":{
            '      "month":"-",
            '      "monthID":"-",
            '      "globex":"141,803",
            '      "openOutcry":"0",
            '      "totalVolume":"143,574",
            '      "blockVolume":"114",
            '      "efpVol":"1,657",
            '      "efrVol":"0",
            '      "eooVol":"0",
            '      "efsVol":"0",
            '      "subVol":"0",
            '      "pntVol":"1,771",
            '      "tasVol":"1,553",
            '      "deliveries":"40",
            '      "opnt":"-",
            '      "aon":"-",
            '      "atClose":"500,216",
            '      "change":"-897",
            '      "strike":"-",
            '      "exercises":"0"
            '   },
            '   "monthData":[
            '      {
            '         "month":"DEC 2023",
            '         "monthID":"DEC-2023-Calls",
            '         "globex":"0",
            '         "openOutcry":"0",
            '         "totalVolume":"0",
            '         "blockVolume":"0",
            '         "efpVol":"0",
            '         "efrVol":"0",
            '         "eooVol":"0",
            '         "efsVol":"0",
            '         "subVol":"0",
            '         "pntVol":"0",
            '         "tasVol":"0",
            '         "deliveries":"40",
            '         "opnt":"-",
            '         "aon":"-",
            '         "atClose":"0",
            '         "change":"-40",
            '         "strike":"0",
            '         "exercises":"0"
            '      },
            '      {
            '         "month":"JAN 2024",
            '         "monthID":"JAN-2024-Calls",
            '         "globex":"338",
            '         "openOutcry":"0",
            '         "totalVolume":"338",
            '         "blockVolume":"0",
            '         "efpVol":"0",
            '         ...
            '      ...
            '   ...
            '}
            '
            'We only need the tradeDate and the totals section:
            'Because we need only a few values from a flat herachie,
            'we can get them with some string operations
            '
            quotationMarksAll = Split(.responseText, """")
            
            'The following loop works column by column in the sheet because
            'I just want to show how to get the values you need.
            'If you need a different output, you can do whatever you want here.
            Do
                Select Case quotationMarksAll(quotationMarkOne)
                    Case "tradeDate"
                        ws.Cells(currRow, 1) = "Trade Date"
                        pasteInCell = True
                    Case "globex"
                        ws.Cells(currRow, 1) = "Globex"
                        pasteInCell = True
                    Case "openOutcry"
                        ws.Cells(currRow, 1) = "Open Outcry"
                        pasteInCell = True
                    Case "totalVolume"
                        ws.Cells(currRow, 1) = "Total Volume"
                        pasteInCell = True
                    Case "blockVolume"
                        ws.Cells(currRow, 1) = "Block Volume"
                        pasteInCell = True
                    Case "efpVol"
                        ws.Cells(currRow, 1) = "efp Vol"
                        pasteInCell = True
                    Case "eooVol"
                        ws.Cells(currRow, 1) = "eoo Vol"
                        pasteInCell = True
                    Case "efsVol"
                        ws.Cells(currRow, 1) = "efs Vol"
                        pasteInCell = True
                    Case "subVol"
                        ws.Cells(currRow, 1) = "sub Vol"
                        pasteInCell = True
                    Case "pntVol"
                        ws.Cells(currRow, 1) = "pnt Vol"
                        pasteInCell = True
                    Case "tasVol"
                        ws.Cells(currRow, 1) = "tas Vol"
                        pasteInCell = True
                    Case "deliveries"
                        ws.Cells(currRow, 1) = "Deliveries"
                        pasteInCell = True
                    Case "atClose"
                        ws.Cells(currRow, 1) = "At Close"
                        pasteInCell = True
                    Case "change"
                        ws.Cells(currRow, 1) = "Change"
                        pasteInCell = True
                End Select
                
                If pasteInCell Then
                    ws.Cells(currRow, 2) = quotationMarksAll(quotationMarkOne + 2)
                    currRow = currRow + 1
                    pasteInCell = False
                End If

                quotationMarkOne = quotationMarkOne + 1
            Loop While quotationMarksAll(quotationMarkOne) <> "monthData"
        Else
            MsgBox "JSON not loaded. HTTP status " & .Status
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks you Zwenn, your code helped me a lot. It's giving me required output. I just want to know that where can I find the Product code (you mentioned 437 at the end of URL ) as I need this data for Gold, Silver and other products too. and where can I get this whole URL on website.

Comment: Thank You Zwenn once again. I found the product codes too in web page source under below mentioned "window.productData"  section. :) :)